# perl Catalyst REST action not working

Tags: rest, perl, action, catalyst

So I'm writing a simple API server, and obviously C::C::R is the right answer. I have an action to get a "list of thingies" working fine:

```
package stuff::Controller::Thingy;
use Moose;
use namespace::autoclean;
BEGIN { extends 'Catalyst::Controller::REST'; }
__PACKAGE__->config(namespace => '');

sub thingy : Local : ActionClass('REST') { }

sub thingy_GET :Args(0) :Path("/thingy") {
}
```

This works great. Also yay HashrefInflator and a JSON view. Makes the code really small.

But! If I add a second action to get a single thingy, my original action stops working:

```
sub thingy_GET :Args(1) :Path("/thingy") {
    my ( $self, $c, $thingy_id ) = @_;
}
```

When plackup starts, I get:

```
[debug] Loaded Path actions:
    .-------------------------------------+--------------------------------------.
| Path                                | Private                              |
+-------------------------------------+--------------------------------------+
| /...                                | /default                             |
| /bar/thingy/...                      | /bar/thingy                         |
| /thingy/*                            | /thingy_GET                           |
| /thingy/...                          | /thingy                               |
'-------------------------------------+--------------------------------------'
```

If I call `/thingy` I get:

```
{
    "data": []
}
```

Ideas?

Comment: If I recall correctly you need to have the `:Args(n)` on the `sub thingy`. The `sub thingy_GET` cannot have arguments. It's not an action, it's just a sub. So if you want several different behaviours you have to implement a `sub thingy` and a `sub thingies`, both of which can have `:Path('/thingy')` but different `:Args(n)`. This is what I think is correct, so I'm not writing it up just yet. I know if you want to chain several of these, you chain the `sub thingy : ActionClass('REST')` bit, and not the `thingy_GET`. Should behave in the same way here.

Answer (score 1):

Your second `thingy_GET` function needs a different function name. Perhaps `thingy_GET_list` and `thingy_GET_resource`, or whatever you want.

Answer (score 1):

Subs cannot have the same name, a different attribute is not enough, and Sub::Multi does not help here.

Use `__PACKAGE__->config(action => { …` to configure the actions instead.

Answer (score 0):

OK, that was (relatively) simple. Don't call the subs the same thing. My screen is too small, I missed the:

Subroutine thing_GET redefined at lib/foo/Controller/Thingy.pm line 40.

And yet the docs as far as I read them make no mention.

Fortunately #catalyst yelled at me. And I scrolled up the plackup output.